# What is the best way to import entries for EE6?

Tags: datagrab, ee6

We've previously used [Datagrab](https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/datagrab) to import entries from XML and CSV files into ExpressionEngine sites, however it doesn't look like it is supported for EE6. Is there an alternative add-on that can used to import content? We tried using [Smart Import Export](https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/smart-import-export) but found the documentation to be lacking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An update here for anyone coming across this question now : Datagrab is now available for EE6 (https://expressionengine.com/add-ons/datagrab)